# Ruby find a string in a text file and output the line it's found on

Tags: ruby, file, readlines

I need to add the functionality to output the entire line a string is found on.  So here's the code I have working so far.

```
if type == "asa"
    if File.readlines(file).grep(/http server enabled/).any?
        $httpserver_failures.push(file)
        out.puts "FAILED: does have http enabled"
    else
        $httpserver_passes.push(file)
        out.puts "PASSED: does not have http enabled"
    end
elsif type == "ios"
    if File.readlines(file).grep(/no ip http server/).any?
        $httpserver_failures.push(file)
        out.puts "FAILED: does have http enabled"
    else
        $httpserver_passes.push(file)
        out.puts "PASSED: does not have http enabled"
    end
end
```

So I just need to add a line to also output the line as it's found.  I just don't know the syntax.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you’re looking for [something like this](http://jezenthomas.com/seven-languages/ruby-day-two/#toc_7)

Answer (score 3):

[`grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) method takes a block also. Thus I think you could write as below :

```
if type == "asa"
  File.readlines(file).grep(/http server enabled/) do |line|
    unless line.empty?
      $httpserver_failures.push(file)
      out.puts "FAILED: does have http enabled"
      puts line # output the line
    else
      $httpserver_passes.push(file)
      out.puts "PASSED: does not have http enabled"
    end
  end
elsif type == "ios"
  File.readlines(file).grep(/no ip http server/) do |line|
    unless line.empty?
      $httpserver_failures.push(file)
      out.puts "FAILED: does have http enabled"
      puts line # output the line
    else
      $httpserver_passes.push(file)
      out.puts "PASSED: does not have http enabled"
    end
  end
end
```